# When app is in background didReceiveRemoteNotification not called with Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase

With Firebase I send this JSON:

```
{
  "data": {
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "to": "xxxxx",
  "content-available": "true",
  "notification": {
    "body": "HI!",
    "title": "FCM Message",
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "Default"
  }
}
```

But `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler` is not called when app is in background.

I enable background Modes - Remote notifications from capabilities.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your key/value for content-available is incorrect.  The key is `content_available` (underscore, not dash) and the value is a boolean, not string:

```
{
  "data": {
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "to": "xxxxx",
  "content_available": true,  // <= CHANGED
  "notification": {
    "body": "HI!",
    "title": "FCM Message",
    "badge": 1,
    "sound": "Default"
  }
}
```

See [Table 1 of the HTTP Server Protocol document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table1):

> On iOS, use this field to represent content-available in the APNs
>   payload. When a notification or message is sent and this is set to
>   true, an inactive client app is awoken. On Android, data messages wake
>   the app by default. On Chrome, currently not supported.

Comment: This is what Firebase generated! In server side you set ContentAvailable property and the name controlled by Firebase library.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you turn on the background modes for remote notifications, If not then click on workspace and go in capabilities and turn on background modes

[image]
As shown in image last option for remote notification check this option